# Copying FBX animation to armature

Tags: animation, import

Here is the Unreal Engine mannequin and several animations: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/File:ThirdPerson_FBX.zip

I am trying to have the mannequin use those animations. I tried copying the animation using Make Links > Animation Data (selecting both armatures and hitting Ctrl-L) however the mannequin mesh then disappears.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong and would appreciate some expert input :)

I'm using the following import settings for the FBX (which I found via their documentation or forum somewhere, as suggested by a staff member I recall):

[image: FBX import settings for UE4]

Update: it turns out if I import the mannequin with the above settings, but then import the animation FBX with -Z Forward and -Y Up then I can make it animate by changing the Object in the mannequin's Armature modifier settings to be root.001 (the armature of the animation) -- the only problem is the character is then running lying down on his back (in line with the animation armature), but I can rotate that to correct I guess.

Trying the same orientation for the import of the animation as for the mannequin import blew up the character. I'm still not sure I'm going about things the right way re applying imported animations.