# Importing individual animations from multiple .FBX files

Tags: animation, import, .fbx

Basically, I have multiple .FBX files from a game Asset I bought with one containing the actual mesh of the model and it's rig but no animation and the other .FBXs containing one animation each. The problem is that the Rest Position for each animation is different (despite them all using the same armature and bone names etc.). For example my "base" Armature is in a standing Rest Position and one animation I am trying to import is a couching walk animation. The Rest Position of the .FBX with the animation however is already in a crouching Rest Pose. How do I get this to work?

I have found this question which seems to be about the same problem, but I am not sure how to use the code provided by the answer:
[Two armature, two rest pose, fixing animations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74672/two-armature-two-rest-pose-fixing-animations)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly prevents you from using the code?

Comment: [Also related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72120/create-pose-from-existing-armature)  Edit the code, replace "Biped[.001]" with the names of your armature objects. (The original and the new rest - posed copy)

Comment: I am not sure where I am supposed to put the code to use it, I've only ever used Add-ons which I put in the addons folder and then activate via the User Preferences window. I tried putting the code into a .py file and putting said file into the addons folder but it didn't show up in blender. I assume I have to use the Python console window but I have no idea how. Do I have to edit the code beforehand (change names of armatures) and then paste it in the console?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I just had to paste it in the text editor window, adjust the names of the armatures and click run script.