# Copy/Paste pose operator not working

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I am trying to copy the pose of an armature to another armature. I was, unfortunately, unable to find a solution that would work for me. Both of the armatures have the same amount of bones that are named identically. I tried using the *Pose -> Copy pose* operator, however when I try to paste the pose into the second armature, nothing happens. Before copying the pose, I first select all of the bones. Are there some specific naming conventions that I have to follow, or could the issue be entirely different? I am importing both of the armatures from an .fbx file. Below is a hiearchy of both the armatures.

[image: The armature I am trying to copy the pose from]

[image: The armature I am trying to paste the pose to]

Comment: The operations you described work well for me. Would you mind sharing your blend file ? You can remove everything except the two armature and the pose you want to Copy/Paste.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, here is the blend file. https://pasteall.org/blend/78f0a6a6a769469890dc719025b552ea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your second armature "Armature.001", the mode "Rest Position" is enabled. That prevents you from modifying the pose.

Select "Armature.001", go to "Object Data" properties, then select "Pose position" instead of "Rest position". The Copy/Paste operation should now work as intended.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I haven't noticed that! However, I am still doing something wrong, or perhaps I have misunderstood the mechanics of armature poses entirely. I have switched the Armature.001 to "Pose position", but I am still unable to reach the desired effect. My understanding was that after pasting the pose, the two armatures should look identical (the bones should all have the same settings as in the second armature). Is this understanding wrong? Currently, when I copy/paste, I do get the little pop-up menu, but nothing happens (at least that I am aware of).

Comment: No, they shouldn't look identical - unless Armature.001 is a perfect copy of Armature ; but, what would be the point ? But "RigSpine1" and "RigSpine2" should have the same relative transform in both armatures.

Comment: Also, I noticed you're in Pose Mode with both armatures selected. As far as I know, it's not a good idea for this kind of operation. You should select an armature in object mode, switch to pose mode, ctrl+c ; switch to object mode, select the other armature, switch to pose mode, ctrl+v. Multi-edit in Blender is a work in progress, so a lot of things don't work "naturally" for now...

Comment: Ahh, that is probably where I went wrong, I completely misunderstood how the posing coordinate system works. I have now noticed in the documentation, that poses are determined by an offset from their rest position, so it makes sense now why "nothing happened" in my eyes (please correct me if I said it wrong). 

The root problem for me is that I have a skinned model saved as fbx file and a bunch of animations also as fbx files. The animations are however not skinned, so I have to transfer the animation action to the skinned model. The animations however have different "default" poses.

Comment: And because the default poses are not identical, when I apply the animation to the skinned armature, the animation looks "messed up". I was trying to copy the bone settings, so that both the armatures look identical, but I now see that I misunderstood how poses function. Is there any easy way to achieve my goal? Is it possible to easily skin the animation, or is it possible to copy the "default/rest" pose position to the skinned model, so that the applied animation works properly?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I have finally found the solution. I will mark your answer as the solution, as the error was on my side for not understanding the mechanics properly. I have also added a link to the post, which contained the information I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution to my problem, which was unrelated to the question I asked due to the initial lack of understanding on my side. I was trying to copy the "absolute transforms" of the bones, which can be achieved by adding "Copy transforms" bone constraints to each bone. Thankfully [a script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74672/two-armature-two-rest-pose-fixing-animations) exists, which automates the process and produces the results I was after.